# how to use replaceChild with getElementById() to switch the xsl that is used

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, xslt

So, I'm working on a page that uses xsl on an xml to create an html table.  When someone clicks a button, I'd like the xsl used to change.  I'm working on the javascript and I think I'm very close but I just can't get it right.

```
function sort()
{
  xsl=loadXMLDoc("sort.xsl");
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  sortedDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.replaceChild(sortedDocument,getElementById('content'));
}
```

I can get this to work with appendChild pretty easily but then it adds the new table at the end instead of replacing the current table with the new sorted table.

Right now, with the replaceChild() method, I keep getting an error:"getElementById" is not defined

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified line: you missed `document`.

```
                            //-----------\/
  document.replaceChild(sortedDocument, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: that did make the "getElementById" error go away but now I have a new error: "node was not found"  any idea what that means?

Comment: is sortedDocument child of body? is so use document.body.replaceChild(sortedDocument,getElementById('content'));

Comment: Thanks so much! :D  that did the trick! you saved me so many headaches!

Comment: There is one another thing.  I don't know if you have any suggestions.  Now that I've got that working, I'm making multiple buttons that will load different xsl files when clicked.  I keep getting an invalid pointer error after the first selection, and I'm unable to switch from new xsl to new xsl.

Comment: I believe you should ask another question regarding your problem with explanation. by the way I don't have any idea about xsl. Sorry